# Evaluating double-slit experiment for wave-particle duality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

Is it possible that the wave-like behavior of particles in double slit experiments is just an outcome of particle distribution? Can we regard or treat a normal or Gaussian distribution as wave-like?

Supposing the pegs on a [Galton board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine) could be arranged to produce distributions of marbles analogous to particles on the screen in the double-slit experiment. Would the marbles be considered to be behaving as a "wave"?

Comment: No, because interference patterns are created in experiments where only one electron at a time is passing through the slits.

Comment: Wave particle duality is a very old and abandoned concept with no applications in physics. It has been replaced with the well defined concept of quantum fields, which are field like objects that only interact by exchange of quanta, which are states of these fields. Quantum fields can, under the right (observer dependent!) circumstances, produce particle like behavior, e.g. so called "particle tracks" in matter. These are artifacts of the special circumstances of these interactions and are not primary physical phenomena that describe the "nature" of these fields.

Comment: Do the quantum fields describe couplings between particles and explain the DSX, even those that have been fired individually at a rate of one per minute ? And if so, what is the physical basis for these couplings ?

Comment: @JohnRennie Since no one has yet demonstrated openly a modified double slit Galton board I would better remain skeptical if the single photon DS slit experiment could not be emulated classically. https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-randomness-can-arise-from-determinism-20191014/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the wavelike behavior in a double slit experiment is just the outcome of particle distribution. One example is on my link at the top of my page.

I do not believe that propagating photons, in slit experiments are being influenced by a Galton board type medium. I do agree with Einstein, that somethings happening but we don’t have all the answers.

On the other hand, something like a Galton board can offer a good analogy. For instance, say we have a box sitting on four short legs with a small hole in the center on top. You can’t see, hear or feel what’s happening inside but when you drop balls into the hole, they always form a wave/interference pattern at the bottom where they fall out.

No one can explain this strange behavior, but a few geniuses come up with an extremely accurate formula that perfectly predicts the observed results. They call it QM, and some even say the mystery inside this box has in it the heart of QM.

Einstein agrees the formula works but still believes there’s some unknown hidden process happening inside. With all his genius even, he fails to come up with a physical model to describe this strange behavior. He never gives up trying until the day he dies.

Most everyone was happy with the formula and as time went by less and less people cared about what caused it.

Every now and then someone takes the time to re-visit this mystery and wonders what’s really going on inside the box. They think about it and right or wrong they offer solutions.

Even though some of these physical solutions match the QM prediction, the consensus is to just except the formula (because its perfect) even though it has no physical explanation.

So, in my opinion, it is possible that the wave/interference behavior happening at the bottom of the box is the outcome of some deterministic, hidden, and physical process that we cannot see.

If someone placed this box on your table and demonstrated this great mystery, would you wonder (like people use to) what's going on inside the box, or would you just except the formula as the explanation?

Comment: I performed the Galton Board experiment. Results can be seen at the following link. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-E70sq0D00

Comment: @Vanick Borg This should have done its way to Breaking science news! An alternative proposed DS Galton Board experiment that allows interference can be also found here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/16P3bkv1FzL1pKlBiM_nP2u4jfk1PDep5/view?usp=sharing_Galton_Board_Double_Slit_Experiment . You are probably the only current researcher that will have the interest to actually implement it and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest possible analogy to a Galton board will be a quantised electric field, interacting between the electric fields of surface electrons from the edges of a slit and the electric field of the particle (an electron or a photon), one direct to the slit.

A common field would explain even the longtime distribution pattern from single shoted particles and even for single edges (fringes appear not only behind double slits or single slits, but also behind every sharp edge). There is no need in self interference if single particles.

Since such common field is not discovered we have to stay with the interpretation of the intensity distribution behind edges, based on a wave-particle duality.